# Check Postgres access for a user

Tags: postgresql, privileges, data-dictionary

I have looked into the documentation for `GRANT` Found [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-grant.html) and I was trying to see if there is a built-in function that can let me look at what level of accessibility I have in databases. Of course there is:

`\dp` and `\dp mytablename`

But this does not show what my account has access to. I would like to see ALL the tables I have access to. Can anyone tell me if there is a command that can check my level of access in Postgres (whether I have `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` privileges)? And if so, what would that command be?

Comment: `\du`?, or query the grants table in information_schema directly.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You could query the `table_privileges` table in the information schema:

```
SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, privilege_type
FROM   information_schema.table_privileges 
WHERE  grantee = 'MY_USER'
```

Comment: And you can only see rows that your db user is allowed to see.

Comment: It still doesn't tell me whether the use is admin or not?

Answer (score 7):

For all users on a specific database, do the following:

```
# psql
\c your_database
select grantee, table_catalog, privilege_type, table_schema, table_name from information_schema.table_privileges order by grantee, table_schema, table_name;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this to list Grantee too and remove (PG_monitor and Public) for Postgres PaaS Azure.

```
SELECT grantee,table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, privilege_type
FROM   information_schema.table_privileges 
WHERE  grantee not in ('pg_monitor','PUBLIC');
```

Comment: only this command worked for me since it showed the role permissions..