# SQL Conditional Union Across Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, union

I have a view with 3 unions combining datasets from 4 different databases.  It works fine if the user has access to all 4, but it does fail if a user doesn't have access to any one of the databases queried.  Is there a way to have the query return the data from only the databases they have access to without failing?

Something like this:

```
IF USERACCESS TO DB1 = TRUE
(SELECT A,B,C
FROM DB1..TABLE1
UNION ALL
)
IF USERACCESS TO DB2 = TRUE
(SELECT A,B,C
FROM DB2..TABLE1
UNION ALL
)
IF USERACCESS TO DB3 = TRUE
(SELECT A,B,C
FROM DB3..TABLE1
)
```

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Could you check their access? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917508/check-postgres-access-for-a-user

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Sorry, SQL Server

Comment: If exists(select * from table)